# Help with local coordinates computations-differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-manifolds

I am reading a lecture notes on differential forms and tangent bundles on complex manifolds and I got stuck on one line where the author does not explain how he did the computation:

Let $\displaystyle \xi=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}(z)d\bar{z_i}\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}.$ Now If we apply this "operator" to $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z_i}$, according to the author we get $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z_i} +\sum_{i}a_{i,j}(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}.$  But according to my calculations I should get only
$\displaystyle\sum_{i}a_{i,j}(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}.$

Am I missing something? or is this a typo?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: That seems to be a typo. Which lecture notes are you reading?

Comment: @John I am reading [these notes](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~cschnell/pdf/notes/kodaira.pdf) by C.Schnell

Comment: I guess he meant that $TM'_{0,1}$ is spanned by the images of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z_i}$ under $\text{id}+\xi$, right?

Comment: Yes you are right, as $v\in TM'_{0,1}$ is decomposed into $v = \pi^{0,1} v + \pi^{1,0}v$.